# Swift 4: Passing from table view to view controller - Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I've spend hours looking at identical questions but none of the answers I've found are helping this issue. Need data from Firebase Database passes to another view controller from the tableview.
P.D. Data to need to be displayed is not in cell, I need to get from firebase from ID which is clicked form table view row.
I've and photo handwritten to explain what I need.
[image]

Here is my code from VC 1:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return guestsList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guestCell", for: indexPath) as! GuestTableViewCell
    let guest: GuestModel
    guest = guestsList[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.guestNameLabel.text = guest.guestName
    cell.attendingLabel.text = guest.attendingStatus
    cell.menuLabel.text = guest.menuStatus
    cell.ageLabel.text = guest.ageStatus
    cell.tableLabel.text = guest.tableNo
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedGuest = guestsList[indexPath.row]
    
    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "GuestDetail") as! GuestDetailsViewController
    
    controller.guestUser = selectedGuest
   self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let guest = guestsList[indexPath.row]
        self.guestsList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.guestsTableView.reloadData()
        self.deleteGuest(id: guest.id!)
    }
}
```

And VC 2

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var guestDetail = [GuestModel]()
var guestUser: GuestModel?
var documenID: String?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
  showGuestDetails()
  
}

func showGuestDetails(){
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!).child("guests")
    ref.queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        
        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
            self.guestDetail.removeAll()

            for guests in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                let guestObject = guests.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let name = guestObject?["guestName"]
                let familyName = guestObject?["guestFamilyName"]
                let phone = guestObject?["guestPhoneNumber"]
                let email = guestObject?["guestEmail"]

                let guest = GuestModel(guestName: name as? String, guestFamilyName: familyName as! String, guestPhoneNumber: phone as? String, guestEmail: email as? String)


                self.phoneNoLabel.text = guest.guestPhoneNumber
                self.emailLabel.text = guest.guestEmail
            }
        }
    }
    self.nameLabel.text = guestUser!.guestName
}'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired result via 2 ways:

1. Pass the autoId from 1st VC to 2nd Detail VC, and in `showGuestDetails()` make your reference as

   ```
   ref = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!).child("guests").child(passedAutoID)
   ```
2. Keeep the same reference but use if condition to check if the user is same as required

   ```
   for guests in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
        let guestObject = guests.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        guard let email = guestObject?["guestEmail"] as? String,
              email != guestUser?.email else {
              continue
        }

        let name = guestObject?["guestName"]
        let familyName = guestObject?["guestFamilyName"]
        let phone = guestObject?["guestPhoneNumber"

        let guest = GuestModel(guestName: name as? String, guestFamilyName: familyName as! String, guestPhoneNumber: phone as? String, guestEmail: email as? String)
        self.nameLabel.text = guest.guestName
        self.phoneNoLabel.text = guest.guestPhoneNumber
        self.emailLabel.text = guest.guestEmail
    }
   ```

Comment: Cuz I'm new in swift, can you tell me where to define the passedAutoID? Also with second example I get this message "Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject?' and 'String?'"

Comment: For 1. you have to keep it in your 1st VC and pass it to your 2nd VC. You can easily get it via prinitng your firebase dict and saving the value in a variable. For 2. I have edited the answer, please check.